# Pandas DataFrame update cell values from second DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have two DataFrames: df1 and df2. df2 beeing a subframe of df1. Eg:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(index=[0,1,2,3,4],columns=['a','b','c']).fillna(0)

df2=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],index=[0,2,4],columns=['b'])
```

Is there a more elegant, implicit version of this:

```
df1.loc[df2.index,df2.columns]=df2.values
```

And why would it be preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1.update(df2)
```

The operation is **in place** (no output), and might change the type of the data.

resulting `df1`:

```
   a    b  c
0  0  1.0  0
1  0  0.0  0
2  0  2.0  0
3  0  0.0  0
4  0  3.0  0
```

A workaround to help getting `integer` type is to use `convert_dtypes` on `df2`:

```
df1.update(df2.convert_dtypes())
```

output:

```
   a  b  c
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  2  0
3  0  0  0
4  0  3  0
```